# Definition of Duality (opposed to Symmetry)

Tags: string-theory, symmetry, terminology, definition, duality

I'm learning basic string theory right now and we came across T-duality which was presented as a symmetry of the formula for the mass of a string in the context of compactification. There was a remark that it can be shown that this is actually a symmetry of the whole theory.

So, why are we introducing a new term [duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality) when we refer simply to a [symmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry) in the theory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Duality* always refers to the idea that two superficially different concepts are actually, in a certain sense, equivalent. Since symmetries, rather tautologically, are equivalences, a duality often occurs as a discrete $\mathbb{Z}_2$-symmetry.

[T-duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-duality) in particular, is the duality between a string theory compactified on a circle of radius $R$ with a theory compactified on the circle with radius $\frac{1}{R}$. In a certain sense, this is a duality between "IR physics" and "UV physics".

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by *"Since symmetries, rather tautologically, are equivalences, a duality often occurs as a discrete ℤ2-symmetry."*?

Comment: @quan: You can always view the thing you get after any transformation as a "new theory". If the transformation is a symmetry, then, *by definition of a symmetry*, the new theory is the same as the old. Since duality relates only two possible theories, applying the duality twice gives back the original theory. The "symmetry group" of a duality is thus $\mathbb{Z}_2$ - a single transformation that, when applied twice, is just the identity.

Comment: Just for clarification: T-duality is a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry only for compactifications on a single circle. In the more general case the group is something bigger. For example, for the heterotic string in d-dimensions the T-duality group is $O(d,d+16,\mathbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 1):

To help elucidate the concept of a *duality*, consider the Ising model in statistical mechanics. At low temperature we  can expand the partition function as,

$$Z=2e^{2N\beta J}\left(1+Ne^{-8\beta J} + 2N e^{-12\beta J} + \dots \right)$$

using diagrammatic methods. In the regime of high temperature, we may expand it as,

$$Z=2^N (\cosh \beta J)^{2N} \left( 1+N(\tanh\beta J)^4 + 2N(\tanh \beta J)^6 + \dots \right).$$

Notice both these theories are related by the exchange $e^{-2\beta J} \leftrightarrow \tanh \beta J$, known as *Kramers-Wannier duality*. From this example, we see a *duality* is a relation between two or more theories, though it is not always a concrete, rigorous concept. Tong refers to this as a 'symmetry of the partition function' under the interchange of the variables. It can be regarded as  a symmetry in that the exchange maintains the fact that the partition function is still describing an aspect of the Ising model.

For the bosonic string, the interchange of quantum numbers and radii $R \leftrightarrow \alpha'/R$ reflects the fact that the spectrum of the string is the same for both circles. The concept extends to more complicated systems. For a superconformal non-linear sigma model describing the dyanmics of a worldsheet, under certain restrictions, exchanging the target space, a Calabi-Yau manifold, for another leads to the same theory. This is known as *mirror symmetry.*

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not really answer my question. So which property makes a duality a duality and not a symmetry of the theory? Or is this question ill-posed?

Comment: @quan It does answer your question, but maybe it's not 100% clear. In some sense, you can think of a duality as a symmetry, but not the other way round. The former relates separate theories to one another.