# Dualities in Physics and Fourier Transforms

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, definition, fourier-transform, duality

In many articles, authors compare physical dualities to Fourier transforms.

For example:

1. Joseph Polchinski, in his article "String Duality" (hep-th/9607050v2), writes: "Weak/strong duality [...] is similar to a Fourier transform, where a function which becomes spread out in position space can become very narrow in momentum space. Here though, the Fourier transform is in a complicated nonlinear field space."
2. Cumrun Vafa, in his article "Geometric Physics"(hep-th/9810149v1), writes: "...duality [...] in some sense is a nonlinear infinite-dimensional generalization of the Fourier transform."

I understand their points, but since these articles are from 1996 and 1998, I wanted to know if someone has, since then, found a more general/precise mathematical definition **that would make dualities manifest** (paraphrasing Nathan Seiberg - see link below).

Summing up, what I am looking for is:

1. Some procedure to identify if a theory has a dual theory.
2. A method to determine this dual theory.

Quoting Nathan Seiberg ([www.icts.res.in/sites/default/files/KAWS2018-2018-01-08-Nathan-Seiberg-1.pdf](http://www.icts.res.in/sites/default/files/KAWS2018-2018-01-08-Nathan-Seiberg-1.pdf)), "we should not be surprised by duality!"

I don't need (nor have any hope of finding) a rigorous mathematical definition. Just something slightly more general and expressed in more mathematical terms (compared to the papers I mentioned above) would already be fantastic.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/162027

Comment: Thanks! I should have been more specific, sorry. But S-duality is the one that I am mostly worried about. I was also considering T-duality but S-duality is the my main concern.

Comment: - and, to be clear, you are asking about S-duality in the context of supersymmetric gauge theories as well, or just string theory? I ask because S-duality, based on the broad principle of taking the reciprocal of the coupling constant, manifests itself in a *lot* of different ways in the former, but in the latter, it is just as deep but there are only two such S-dualities: type I $\leftrightarrow$ type SO(32) het. and type IIB self duality

Comment: SUSY gauge theories. Thanks!